# Uniswap JS SDK returns invalid pair address for two ERC20 tokens in hardhat network

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I create two ERC20 tokens, deploy them with hardhat on hardhat network, then create Uniswap pair, then retrieve its address with SDK's `Fetcher` and with my contract. Fetcher returns different address than the one I get in my contract. If I manually substitute the address in `sdk.cjs.development.js` with the address from the contract, all works, otherwise `Fetcher` reverts.

So, here is the hardhat script:

```
const UniswapV2FactoryArtifact = require('@uniswap/v2-core/build/UniswapV2Factory.json');
const UniswapV2Router02Artifact = require('@uniswap/v2-periphery/build/UniswapV2Router02.json');


const moment = require('moment');

const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

// Uniswap sdk
const { Token, Fetcher } = require('@uniswap/sdk')
const hre = require('hardhat');
const chainId = hre.config.networks.hardhat.chainId;


async function testSDK(skillTokenAddress, fakeDAEAddress) {
  const SKILL = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, skillTokenAddress,  ethers.provider);
  const FakeDAE = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, fakeDAEAddress,  ethers.provider);
  const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(FakeDAE, SKILL, ethers.provider);
  console.log(pair)
}

async function main() {

  const signers = await ethers.getSigners();
  // for (const signer of signers) {
  //   const balance = await signer.getBalance();
  //   console.log(signer.address, ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance))

  // }

  const UniswapV2Factory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    UniswapV2FactoryArtifact.abi,
    UniswapV2FactoryArtifact.bytecode
  );

  const uniswapV2Factory = await UniswapV2Factory.deploy(signers[0].address);

  const UniswapV2Router02 = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    UniswapV2Router02Artifact.abi,
    UniswapV2Router02Artifact.bytecode
  );
  const uniswapV2Router02 = await UniswapV2Router02.deploy(uniswapV2Factory.address, signers[0].address);
  await uniswapV2Router02.deployed();
  
  const SkillToken = await ethers.getContractFactory('SkillToken');
  const skillToken = await SkillToken.deploy();
  await skillToken.deployed();
  
  const FakeDAE = await ethers.getContractFactory('FakeDAE');
  const fakeDAE = await FakeDAE.deploy();
  await fakeDAE.deployed();
  
  await fakeDAE.approve(uniswapV2Router02.address, 10000);
  await skillToken.approve(uniswapV2Router02.address, 10000);

  console.log(`Skill Address: ${skillToken.address}, FakeDAE address: ${fakeDAE.address}`)

  await expect(uniswapV2Factory.createPair(skillToken.address, fakeDAE.address))
    .to.emit(uniswapV2Factory, "PairCreated"); 

  
  await uniswapV2Router02.addLiquidity(
    skillToken.address, 
    fakeDAE.address,
    8000,
    8000,
    7999,
    7999,
    signers[0].address,
    moment().add(10, 'seconds').unix()
  );

  await uniswapV2Router02.swapTokensForExactTokens(
    1,
    2,
    [fakeDAE.address, skillToken.address],
    signers[0].address,
    moment().add(1, 'minutes').unix()
  );

  const LiqCalc = await ethers.getContractFactory('LiqCalc');
  const liqCalc = await LiqCalc.deploy(uniswapV2Factory.address);
  await liqCalc.deployed();
  const info = await liqCalc.pairInfo(skillToken.address, fakeDAE.address);
  console.log(info)
  
  await testSDK(skillToken.address, fakeDAE.address);



  
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

We deployed two ERC20 tokens, `Skill` and `FakeDAE`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

// for debug
import "hardhat/console.sol";


contract SkillToken is ERC20, AccessControl {
  uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 12000;
  bytes32 public constant BURNER_ROLE = keccak256("BURNER_ROLE");

  function decimals() public view override returns (uint8) {
    console.log('Skill token decimals');
    return 18;
  }

  constructor() ERC20("SkillToken", "SKILL") {
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());
    _mint(_msgSender(), INITIAL_SUPPLY);
  }

  function burn(address from, uint256 amount) public {
    require(hasRole(BURNER_ROLE, _msgSender()), "Caller is not a burner");
    _burn(from, amount);
  }

}
```

and `FakeDAE` is analogeous.

`LiqCal` is a contract which reports the valid pair address:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol';
import '@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol';

import "hardhat/console.sol";


contract LiqCalc  {
    address public factory;
    constructor(address factory_) public {
        factory = factory_;
    }

    function pairInfo(address tokenA, address tokenB) public view returns (uint reserveA, uint reserveB, uint totalSupply) {
        IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB));
        console.log('LiqCal, pair addr:', address(pair));
        totalSupply = pair.totalSupply();
        (uint reserves0, uint reserves1,) = pair.getReserves();
        (reserveA, reserveB) = tokenA == pair.token0() ? (reserves0, reserves1) : (reserves1, reserves0);
    }
 
}
```

which is `0x21e7b0ced250469051a249252a33c7c5eb13a1f6`

However, `Fetcher` returns invalid pair:

```
Fetcher.fetchPairData = function fetchPairData(tokenA, tokenB, provider) {
    console.log(`====> chainA=${tokenA.chainId}, addrA: ${tokenA.address}, chainB =${tokenB.chainId}, addrB: ${tokenB.address}`)
    try {
      console.log(`typeof provider: ${typeof provider}`)
      if (provider === undefined) provider = providers.getDefaultProvider(networks.getNetwork(tokenA.chainId));
      !(tokenA.chainId === tokenB.chainId) ? "development" !== "production" ? invariant(false, 'CHAIN_ID') : invariant(false) : void 0;
      var address = Pair.getAddress(tokenA, tokenB);
      console.log(`Pair address in Fetcher: ${address}, substituted: 0x21e7b0ced250469051a249252a33c7c5eb13a1f6`)

      address = '0x21e7b0ced250469051a249252a33c7c5eb13a1f6';
      return Promise.resolve(new contracts.Contract(address, IUniswapV2Pair.abi, provider).getReserves()).then(function (_ref) {
        var reserves0 = _ref[0],
            reserves1 = _ref[1];
        var balances = tokenA.sortsBefore(tokenB) ? [reserves0, reserves1] : [reserves1, reserves0];
        return new Pair(new TokenAmount(tokenA, balances[0]), new TokenAmount(tokenB, balances[1]));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  };
```

from console.log:

```
Pair address in Fetcher: 0x7818b27560325CD29600237a5a14880b6f392Ea8, substituted: 0x21e7b0ced250469051a249252a33c7c5eb13a1f6
```

When I don't not substitute inside `Fetcher` my pair, `getReserves()` reverts obviously, because no such pair exists.

The entire log from the run with *substituted* pair address (all works):

```
npx hardhat run scripts/uniswap-script.js 
Skill Address: 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0, FakeDAE address: 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9
LiqCal, pair addr: 0x21e7b0ced250469051a249252a33c7c5eb13a1f6
[
  BigNumber { _hex: '0x1f3f', _isBigNumber: true },
  BigNumber { _hex: '0x1f42', _isBigNumber: true },
  BigNumber { _hex: '0x1f40', _isBigNumber: true },
  reserveA: BigNumber { _hex: '0x1f3f', _isBigNumber: true },
  reserveB: BigNumber { _hex: '0x1f42', _isBigNumber: true },
  totalSupply: BigNumber { _hex: '0x1f40', _isBigNumber: true }
]
Skill token decimals
Fake token decmals
====> chainA=31337, addrA: 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9, chainB =31337, addrB: 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0
typeof provider: object
Calling Pair get address for A: 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9, B: 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0
Pair address in Fetcher: 0x7818b27560325CD29600237a5a14880b6f392Ea8, substituted: 0x21e7b0ced250469051a249252a33c7c5eb13a1f6
Calling Pair get address for A: 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0, B: 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9
Pair {
  liquidityToken: Token {
    decimals: 18,
    symbol: 'UNI-V2',
    name: 'Uniswap V2',
    chainId: 31337,
    address: '0x7818b27560325CD29600237a5a14880b6f392Ea8'
  },
  tokenAmounts: [
    TokenAmount {
      numerator: [JSBI],
      denominator: [JSBI],
      currency: [Token],
      token: [Token]
    },
    TokenAmount {
      numerator: [JSBI],
      denominator: [JSBI],
      currency: [Token],
      token: [Token]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Facing the exact same error. Did you ever find a solution? `Pair.getAddress` simply returns an invalid address for many different token pairs that I tried. Quite confusing

Comment: @NamanyayG I gave up on using their SDK and communicate with the contract itself through ethers.js.